# What is Variance and Standard Deviation??

Tags: statistics

I know both, and ofc S.d is just the root of variance and I have completed numerous problems on them but I don't understand their significance and wider application.
Thank you!

Comment: You could check [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/132914/what-exactly-are-moments-how-are-they-derived) post out on our Cross Validated site. Also search there using 'sd' or 'variance' as the keyword to see some popular questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It gives you a measure of the variability implicit in a random event. If you do an experiment where you toss a coin 100 times and repeat this experiment many times you know that on average you will get 50 heads and 50 tails. For any one set of 100 tosses you will probably get something different. Say 51:49 or 42:58. It is the variance which gives you information on how wide that spread in outcomes is.